# kotlin: concatenate a string with a Int value

Tags: kotlin, concatenation

I have a model data class. a value of this class is Int (val amount : Int).

When I want initialize this value and concatenate it with a string , give me this error :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 : amount"
```

I use this code to concatenate a string with my Int value.

```
var number = 0
"$number : amount".toInt()
```

So my question is how concatenate a string with Int value ?

Thank's in advanced .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I want initialize this value and concatenate it with a string

You mean `format` and not `toInt` I guess:

```
"%d : amount".format(amount)
```

or by using variable holder:

```
val amount = 1
val output:String = "$amount : amount"
```

---

From documentation of [toInt](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int.html)

> `fun String.toInt(): Int`
>
> Parses the string as an Int number and returns the result.
>
> Exceptions NumberFormatException - **if the string is not a valid
> representation of a number.**

Your String `"1 : amount"` is not a correct number, for that you got `NumberFormatException`

Comment: doesn't work body . I get type mismatch .  "%d : amount".format(number)

Comment: and also this ... val amount = 1
val output:String = "$amount : amount"

Comment: I just need to add some text with my Int value(number) . somthing like this : amount : 0

Comment: @BahadorEslami If I understand, you have an Int and you want to return an Int that look like `amount : 0` ? If this is the case, then it's not possible, you can't return a string as an Int

Comment: So , not possible do this  ///   var num : Int = 1
        var numWithText : Int = "$num : amount"     right ?

Comment: @BahadorEslami Yes you can't use that check the [example](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS40LjEwIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsImpzQ29kZSI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiLyoqXG4gKiBZb3UgY2FuIGVkaXQsIHJ1biwgYW5kIHNoYXJlIHRoaXMgY29kZS4gXG4gKiBwbGF5LmtvdGxpbmxhbmcub3JnIFxuICovXG5cbmZ1biBtYWluKCkge1xuICAgIHZhciBudW0gOiBJbnQgPSAxIFxuICAgIHZhciBudW1XaXRoVGV4dCA6IEludCA9IFwiJG51bSA6IGFtb3VudFwiXG59In0=) it gives you `Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Int was expected` which is logic

Comment: So if I want to achieve this must change the type of my amount to String ...

Comment: You mean to change the `numWithText` to string